# 2 positional arguments expected, but 0 found

Tags: flutter, dart

Can anyone please help me? I don't understand why my code is giving an error.

```
int add (int n1, int n2){
  
  n1 + n2;
  
}

void main() {
  
 int step1Result = add(n1: 5, n2: 9);
  
  print(step1Result);
 
  
}
```

Comment: There's no `javascript` in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've crated positioned constructor but passing data as named constructor.

try like

```dart
  int step1Result = add(  5, 9);
```

Or to create positioned constructor

```dart
int add({required int n1, required int n2}) {
  return n1 + n2;
}

void main() {
  int step1Result = add(n1: 5, n2: 9);

  print(step1Result);
}
```

Check more about [using-constructors](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#using-constructors)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the **return** statement.

```
int add (int n1, int n2){

   return n1 + n2;

}
```

Comment: Error compiling to JavaScript:
Info: Compiling with sound null safety
lib/main.dart:11:23:
Error: Too few positional arguments: 2 required, 0 given.
 int step1Result = add(n1: 5, n2: 9);
                      ^
lib/main.dart:3:5:
Info: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
int add (int n1, int n2){
    ^^^
Error: Compilation failed.

Answer (score 0):

```
add(n1: 5, n2: 9)
```

for calling like this , you need to use -> {} on function , like below

```
int add ({int n1, int n2}){

   return n1 + n2;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dart has two types of parameters: Required and optional parameters,
in optional there are two types named and positional.

In the named ones you specify n1: 5, n2: 9 like you have done,
and in positional you don't need to add the parameter name.

In your case you can choose any one of the below :

1. Required parameter (positional) :

```
int add (int n1, int n2){
  
  n1 + n2;
  
}

void main() {
  
 int step1Result = add(5,9);
  
  print(step1Result);
 
  
}
```

2. Optional parameter (positonal) :

```
int add (int n1, int n2){
  
  n1 + n2;
  
}

void main() {
  
 int step1Result = add([5,9]);
  
  print(step1Result);
 
  
}
```

3. Optional parameter (named):

```
int add ({int n1, int n2}){
  
  n1 + n2;
  
}

void main() {
  
 int step1Result = add(n1: 5, n2: 9);
  
  print(step1Result);
 
  
}
```

(Although named parameters are a kind of optional parameter, you can annotate them with required to indicate that the parameter is mandatory)